# Bootstrap Validation for a interger number with leading zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am validating a form using bootstrap validator . I have given **input type = number** and **min number is 1 and the maximum is 31** .In this scenario, I can give the input as 02 or 2 both should be considered as true , but if I give 2 in input box bootstrap accepts the value,[image]

if I give as 02 it shows the error message . Is there is any another way to accept both the values as true in bootstrap validation ?

**JS: 
bootstrapValidator.min.js**

**HTML**

```
  <input placeholder="DD" class="form-control text-center date_field_input" id="dob_date"  name="dob_date" required type="number" max="31" min="1">
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#appointment_form').bootstrapValidator({
    dob_date: {
                                validators: {
                                    notEmpty: {
                                        message: 'Please enter the date'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You are using type="number" this will always fail on input = 02.

You can try with following,

```
<input placeholder="DD" class="form-control text-center date_field_input" id="dob_date"  name="dob_date" required type="text" pattern="[0-9]{2}" maxlength="31">
```

Comment: Its pattern not patterhn

Comment: ...and I'm not sure you want a `maxlength` of 31. 2 should do it!